# Token Generation for Botframework Webchat

Tags: token, botframework

I've been migrating my Direct Line Bot from Webchat v3 to v4.
The new version demands the use of tokens rather than the Direct Line secret in the calling page.
Here is the code (index.html) used to start the bot:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Web Chat: Full-featured bundle</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/master/webchat.js"></script>

    <style>
         html, body {
            height: 100%
        }

         body {
            margin: 0
        }

         #webchat,
         #webchat > * {
             height: 100%;
             width: 100%;

        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
       <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>

    <script>
    (async function () {
        const res = await fetch('https://bellamspt.azurewebsites.net/Forms/Webchat/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });

      const { token } = await res.json();

      window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token })
      }, document.getElementById('webchat'));

      document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
    })().catch(err => console.error(err));
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Question: 
What code do I need to write to generate the token in other to be called by https://bellamspt.azurewebsites.net/Forms/Webchat/directline/token   ??
Realize it's got to be something like

```
POST https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate
Authorization: Bearer SECRET
```

but I don't know if it's got to be a php, js or other type of file to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to exchange your DirectLine Secret for a token on the backend? If so, how is the backend for `https://bellamspt.azurewebsites.net/` configured - are you using a framework like Express or Restify?

Comment: Yes I am. The https://bellamspt.azurewebsites.net/ is a simple asp.net website. Could please share some pointers about Express or Restify implementation? It would be also great if you could share some reference source code. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used php to solve this. You could give it a try.

```
<?php
$botSecret = '<your secret>';
$response = wp_remote_get( 'https://webchat.botframework.com/api/tokens', array( 'headers' => 'Authorization: BotConnector ' . $botSecret ) );
if( is_array($response) ) {
  $header = $response['headers'];
  $token = $response['body'];
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var webChatToken = <?php echo $token; ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue yesterday, I just post it here in case it helps anyone in the future. If you change your code to this it should work:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Web Chat: Full-featured bundle</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/master/webchat.js"></script>

    <style>
         html, body {
            height: 100%
        }

         body {
            margin: 0
        }

         #webchat,
         #webchat > * {
             height: 100%;
             width: 100%;

        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
       <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>

    <script>
    (async function () {
        const res = await fetch('https://bellamspt.azurewebsites.net/Forms/Webchat/directline/token', 
{ method: 'POST', headers: { Authorization: 'write your direct line secret here' }});

      const { token } = await res.json();

      window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token })
      }, document.getElementById('webchat'));

      document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
    })().catch(err => console.error(err));
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You had to add the authorization in the header of the post request to generate the token in the async function. Unfortunately this might not be obvious from Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) on how the generate the token

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is implement some kind of server side logic using whatever technology you're most comfortable with that uses the secret, which is kept only on your server, to generate a new token by making an HTTP request to the DirectLine channel as you point out above. Then, in your web page's start up logic, you make a request to get that token and, with the token, initialize the direct line instance in the web page. Using this approach ensures that nobody external ever gets a hold of your secret.

So, there is no one type of file to "make it work". You will need to choose Node, PHP, ASP.NET or any other server technology and implement it in the way you would any other HTTP request handler.

[This article will help in understanding the authentication concepts and APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) and [here's a blog post that shows how you might do it with ASP.NET and Node](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/09/01/using-webchat-with-azure-bot-services-authentication/).

Comment: Thx Drew. Still struggling to get it working. Would you have some pointer to a functional end-to-end code sample plse? Cheers